# What is the function of shell

Tags: shell, unix, operating-system

First of all I know very little about UNIX programming. I'm not sure what exactly shell does. I looked it up on the internet and I found that the function of a shell is very similar to that of an operating system. So, what exactly is the difference between an operating system and a shell? Does shell act like an operating system in a UNIX system or is it a part of any operating system?

And also, it would be of great help if someone would give some examples on inter-process communication other than the stand client-server example.

Answer (score 4):

The shell is nothing more than a window into which you can type text operating system commands.  It's the interface, *not* the operating system.  Unix is the OS.

Back when Unix was written, there were no graphical user interfaces.  That text shell was all that we had.

Other examples of inter process communication besides client/server?  Point to point sockets, peer to peer might be another.

Comment: thanks a lot.So does that mean there is not shell in windows systems?And also,i wanted examples of IPC which takes place in the same computer.

Comment: Of course Windows has a shell.  If you're on a Windows box, you are looking at one aspect of it.

Comment: So basically in an operating system,kernel interacts with the hardware and shell interacts with the user.Is my thinking right?

Comment: Stop saying "basically" - it's a high tech "um".  Sure.  Why are you are on about this?

Answer (score 0):

A shell is simply a program. In Unix, essentially any program can be a shell.

The shell can be the program set up to run when a user logs on to the system.
Or the shell can be a program run from that program.

Normally, one thinks of a shell as being a command interpreter. The shell could be a graphical user interface. Or the shell could be some application to administrator wants to lock the user into.

Some systems, for example VMS, have the user interface component integrated into the operating system. The command interpreter (in VMS, DCL) runs in a protected mode and is generally available to applications. That is, if a program is started from the command interpreter, it remains available to the process. In other words, each time you run a program from the command interpreter is you remain in the same process. In Unix, each program run is a separate process.